# WPF: weird problem in dataBinding with TabControl

Tags: wpf, data-binding, tabcontrol

I'm trying to use DataBinding for dynamically populating a TabControl but have a problem. `dataBinding` runs fine but I would like the content of each TabItem to be independent one from the other. Here is my XAML code:

```
<TabControl
    DockPanel.Dock="Left"
    ItemsSource="{Binding OpenChats}"
    Name="tabChats"
    VerticalAlignment="Top"
    Width="571">

    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock
                Text="{Binding Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>

            <TextBox />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>

</TabControl>
```

TabItems are created with different headers (as I want) but when the user types something in the TextBox inside the ContentTemplate, the same text is maintained in different tabItems and I don't want this.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had same problem. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914495/wpf-how-to-programmatically-remove-focus-from-a-textbox) helped me. My solution was to remove focus from textbox when tab changed. When focus from textbox is removed, new content is set to binded property as expected.

```
private void TabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject focusedElement = (FocusManager.GetFocusedElement(tabControl) as DependencyObject);
        if (focusedElement != null)
        {
            DependencyObject ancestor = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(focusedElement);
            while (ancestor != null)
            {
                var element = ancestor as UIElement;
                if (element != null && element.Focusable)
                {
                    element.Focus();
                    break;
                }

                ancestor = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(ancestor);
            }
        }

    }
```

or use

```
Text="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
```

on textbox binding.

Answer (score 0):

The TextBox in the ContentTemplate has no Binding. Try

```
<TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</TabControl.ContentTemplate>
```

Adjust the bindingpath if necessary

Comment: If i do this i see different values in TextBox but when i write a new value in textbox, change tab and return to original tab i lose what i've written. There must be something wrong :-(

Comment: Stick a debug breakpoint in the binding property... what happens?

Comment: When you run the program, are there any Binding Expression Erorrs in the Output Window of Visual Studio? Maybe the Path is wrong.