# WPF MVVM deselect textbox on Enter key press

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

What I want is when for the currently focused textbox to lose focus when the user hits the enter key.  The only way I can think to achieve this is by using input bindings in XAML to bind to a command in code that passes down the entire textbox control to the viewmodel.  I don't like this approach and was hoping someone had a 'clean' way of approaching this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom textbox and put this in the controls code:

```
public partial class CustomTextBox : TextBox
{
    public CustomTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
        if(e.Key == Key.Return)
        Keyboard.ClearFocus();
    }
}
```

Then just use your custom textbox wherever you want that particular behaviour.

Comment: That might actually be better than the way I was planning to do it.  Thanks I'll mark it once I get a chance to play around with it.

Comment: something to note is the KeyBoard.ClearFocus is for .Net 4.0 so if your using something older then check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914495/wpf-how-to-programmatically-remove-focus-from-a-textbox

Answer (score 2):

Quite often you get a password box on login whereby you need to allow the enter key.

```
<PasswordBox VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="txtPassword" Template="{StaticResource PassBoxBaseControlTemplate}" Height="25" BorderBrush="Black" Width="165.031">
   <PasswordBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{Binding ComLoginClickOK}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=txtPassword}"/>
   </PasswordBox.InputBindings>
</PasswordBox>
```