# Manually running UpdateSource when program shuts down causes an exception

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, datagrid

My application needs to **save** its data when it shuts down, so I implemented:

```
private void oclmEditor_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = false;

    OCLMEditorViewModel vm = this.DataContext as OCLMEditorViewModel;
    if (vm.SaveModelDataCommand.CanExecute(null))
        vm.SaveModelDataCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

I thought all was well. But then I realised that whilst it was *saving* at shutdown, it was not actually **updating** the source controls *first*. This really surprised me as they are set to `LostFocus` and clearly everything is losing focus if it is shutting down .

I decided that I needed to find a way of easily getting all the controls to update the source. As a result of my research I implemented these extensions:

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> EnumerateVisualChildren(this DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(dependencyObject); i++)
        {
            yield return VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dependencyObject, i);
        }
    }


    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> EnumerateVisualDescendents(this DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        yield return dependencyObject;

        foreach (DependencyObject child in dependencyObject.EnumerateVisualChildren())
        {
            foreach (DependencyObject descendent in child.EnumerateVisualDescendents())
            {
                yield return descendent;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void UpdateBindingSources(this DependencyObject dependencyObject)
    {
        foreach (DependencyObject element in dependencyObject.EnumerateVisualDescendents())
        {
            LocalValueEnumerator localValueEnumerator = element.GetLocalValueEnumerator();
            while (localValueEnumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                BindingExpressionBase bindingExpression = BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(element, localValueEnumerator.Current.Property);
                if (bindingExpression != null)
                {
                    bindingExpression.UpdateSource();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In all honesty, I do not know what the best name would be to give to the class nor where to store it in the application (I used the mainwindow.xaml.cs).

I digressed ... So, I then changed the shutdown code:

```
private void oclmEditor_Closing(object sender, System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
    e.Cancel = false;

    oclmEditor.UpdateBindingSources();
    OCLMEditorViewModel vm = this.DataContext as OCLMEditorViewModel;
    if (vm.SaveModelDataCommand.CanExecute(null))
        vm.SaveModelDataCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

In principle it works. Now the sources are updated before it saves. Great!

But I noticed in the output window:

> System.Windows.Data Error: 8 : Cannot save value from target back to source. BindingExpression:Path=SelectedStudentItem;
>
> DataItem='OCLMEditorViewModel' (HashCode=32322646); target element is 'DataGrid' (Name='gridStudents');
>
> target property is 'SelectedItem' (type 'Object') NullReferenceException:'System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at OCLMEditor.OCLMEditorViewModel.set_SelectedStudentItem(Student value) in D:\My Programs\OCLMEditor\OCLMEditor\ViewModels\OCLMEditorViewModel.cs:line 151'

The `DataGrid` is bound to a `CollectionViewSource`. The `SelectedItem` is bound to a property in the `ViewModel`. I did more testing and had to end up doing:

```
private Student _SelectedStudentItem;
public Student SelectedStudentItem
{
    get
    {
        return _SelectedStudentItem;
    }
    set
    {
        // We need to remove this item from the previous student history
        if (_SelectedStudentItem != null)
            _SelectedStudentItem.History.Remove(Meeting.DateMeeting);

        _SelectedStudentItem = value;
        if (_SelectedStudentItem == null)
            return;

        _EditStudentButtonClickCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        _DeleteStudentButtonClickCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        OnPropertyChanged("SelectedStudentItem");

        if (ActiveStudentAssignmentType == StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingMain)
        {
            _Meeting.TFGW.BibleReadingItem.Main.Name = _SelectedStudentItem.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged("BibleReadingMain");
        }
        else if (ActiveStudentAssignmentType == StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingClass1)
        {
            _Meeting.TFGW.BibleReadingItem.Class1.Name = _SelectedStudentItem.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged("BibleReadingClass1");
        }
        else if (ActiveStudentAssignmentType == StudentAssignmentType.BibleReadingClass2)
        {
            _Meeting.TFGW.BibleReadingItem.Class2.Name = _SelectedStudentItem.Name;
            OnPropertyChanged("BibleReadingClass2");
        }
    }
}
```

I had to put that test for null in there and return early. Now the exception does not happen.

Do I assume correctly that there was no other way to handle this? One thing I did try was to change my `SelectedStudentItem` to work directly with my collection view `CurrentItem` and `MoveCurrentTo` methods. But then I lose the ability to keep this variable up to date as the user clicks on grid rows. That is why I did it the former way (binding to `SelectedItem`).

Sorry if the question sound wordy or complicated. I was not sure how to convey it.

Comment: *"save its data when it shuts down"* - this is one of the reasons why I don't like `LostFocus` (I use either `PropertyChanged` or a command). So you have window, where user is typing something and he hits `Alt-F4` and you want to save what he is already entered into `TextBox`? Shouldn't be as simple as changing [focus programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2914495/1997232) (so that binding will update source) and delaying exit (if it's needed, not sure)?

Comment: @Sinatr In this case I am just hitting the X in the top right of the window. I also have a File menu with Exit on it. But I have to click on another control for things to update as opposed to a menu item or anything.